# How to close the modal after SetTimeOut and postback occurred

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here is my issue: in my web page I have textbox for email and submit button when the user click on the submit button an email is been sent.That kinda of process taking little bit time so I thought about showing the user a modal window with a loading panel the thing the is after the amount of time that I'm giving the modal to show the window got stuck although the process already finished.

My question is how to close the modal after the SetTimeout of the modal and postback been occurred???

Here is my code and link to code that helped me.
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-loading-progress-image-when-Page-Loads-or-does-PostBack-using-ASPNet.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

      function ShowProgress() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var modal = $('<div />');
                modal.addClass("modal");
                $('body').append(modal);
                var loading = $(".loading");
                loading.show();
                var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            }, 200);
            __doPostBack("<%=btnSubmit.UniqueID %>", "");
             // How to close the modal after 200 sec are over and postback been execute 
        }



   Email:<asp:TextBox name="Email" ID="txtemail" ValidationGroup="Group" runat="server"  Width="330px"/>

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredFieldValidatorEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtemail"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Req" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="Group"
                        CssClass="validationClass"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Email"
                        ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" CssClass="requiredFieldValidateStyle"
                        ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                              <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" ValidationGroup="Group" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="passwordSubmit_Click"   OnClientClick="ShowProgress();"/>
                              <div class="loading" align="center">
                                Loading. Please wait.<br />
                                <br />
                                <img src="Images/Layout/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" />
                              </div>
<style type="text/css">
       .modal
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: black;
            z-index: 99;
            opacity: 0.8;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
            -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .loading
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            border: 5px solid #808080;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: White;
            z-index: 999;
        }
     </style>
```

Back Code:

```
 Protected Sub passwordSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If revEmail.IsValid Then
            Dim dba As New DBAccess
            Dim email As String = ""
            Dim password As String = ""

            Dim ds As DataSet = dba.GetForgotPasswordEmail(m_UserName, txtemail.Text, m_CompanyCode)
            If Not ds Is Nothing Then

                Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)
                email = dr("Email")
                password = dr("Password")
                Dim fpMessage As New SendForgotEmailPassword
                fpMessage.SendForgotPasswordEmail(email, password)
                lblEmailSent.Text = "Email has been sent."
                lbToLoginPage.Visible = True

            Else
                lblEmailSent.Text = "No Such Email."
                lbToLoginPage.Visible = True
            End If
        Else
            lbToLoginPage.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a callback to your postback

```
function ShowProgress() {

        // I guess it shows your modal
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);

        // Gets the request manager
        var requestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        // Callback function will be called after __doPostBack
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            // This will be executed after __doPostBack
            // Here's you should put your code to close modal!

            // Remove the request handler
            requestManager.remove_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        }

        // Tells the request manager we are adding a callback
        requestManager.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

        __doPostBack("<%=btnSubmit.UniqueID %>", "");

    }
```

Comment: The modal is been closed the but there is black page that cover the original page and I can see in the back that the email been sent. like that row is not doing anything :  requestManager.remove_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

Comment: Any other suggestions?